# Derivation of transformation rule for covectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I am currently teaching myself GR and am stuck with an exercise where we have to show that covectors transform under this rule, given two overlapping charts $\phi=(x^1, ... , x^n)$ and $\phi'=(x'^1, ... , x'^n)$
$$\left(dx^\mu\right)_p = \left(\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\nu}\right)_{\phi'(p)}\left(dx'^\nu\right)$$

This whole notation with the p is a bit confusing.
But I think the best place to start is from the definition of a covector, namely covectors are linear maps from Vectors to the reals. So:

$$\left(dx^\mu\right)_p(X)=(X(x^\mu))_p$$
Can one then not combine the maps? So one then has:
$$\left(dx^\mu\right)_p(X)=(X(x^\mu\circ \phi^{-1}))_{\phi(p)}$$
but aren't the $x^\mu$'s already a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show coordinate transformations for the tangent space and the dual tangent space.

To be clear, given $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ for the manifold $M$, I am defining
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)_p := &(\partial_{\mu}(f\circ x^{-1}))(x(p));\\
(df)_p:T_pM &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
X &\longmapsto (df)_p(X) := X(f).
\end{align}
Then we have
\begin{align}
(dx^{\mu})_p\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)_p\right) =\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)_p = (\partial_{\nu}(x^{\mu}\circ x^{-1}))(x(p)) = \delta_{\nu}^{\mu}(x(p)) = \delta_{\nu}^{\mu}.
\end{align}

Now let's consider a change of coordinate chart (for an overlapping region of the manifold) in the tangent space. To do this, I will insert an identity operator. I will call my charts $x$ and $y$ for clarity.
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)_p &= (\partial_{\mu}(f\circ x^{-1}))(x(p)) \\&= (\partial_{\mu}(f\circ y^{-1} \circ y \circ x^{-1}))(x(p)) \\&= (\partial_{\mu}((f\circ y^{-1} )\circ (y \circ x^{-1})))(x(p)) \\&= (\partial_{\mu}(y\circ x^{-1}))^{\nu}(x(p))\cdot(\partial_{\nu}(f\circ y^{-1}))(\underbrace{(y\circ x^{-1})(x(p))}_{y(p)}) \\&=(\partial_{\mu}(y^{\nu}\circ x^{-1}))(x(p))\cdot(\partial_{\nu}(f\circ y^{-1}))(y(p)) \\ &=
\left(\frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)_p\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\nu}}\right)_p.
\end{align}
So we conclude that
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)_p = \left(\frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\nu}}\right)_p.
\end{align}

Now let's look at the following:
\begin{align}
(dx^{\mu})_p\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)_p\right) &=\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)_p \\&= (\partial_{\nu}(x^{\mu}\circ x^{-1}))(x(p)) \\&=(\partial_{\nu}(x^{\mu}\circ y^{-1} \circ y \circ x^{-1}))(x(p)) \\& = (\partial_{\nu}((x^{\mu}\circ y^{-1}) \circ (y \circ x^{-1})))(x(p)) \\& = 
(\partial_{\nu}(y\circ x^{-1}))^{\sigma}(x(p))\cdot(\partial_{\sigma}(x^{\mu}\circ y^{-1}))(\underbrace{(y\circ x^{-1})(x(p))}_{y(p)}) \\&=
(\partial_{\nu}(y^{\sigma}\circ x^{-1}))(x(p))\cdot(\partial_{\sigma}(x^{\mu}\circ y^{-1}))(y(p)) \\&=
\left(\frac{\partial y^{\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)_p\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\right)_p \\&=
\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\right)_p(dy^{\sigma})_p\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right)_p\right).
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
(dx^{\mu})_p = \left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\sigma}}\right)_p(dy^{\sigma})_p,
\end{align}
as you wanted. Please ask if anything is unclear, or you think I have made a mistake.

Comment: That's a really good and detailed answer. Thanks!